# Form Load 'triggering' rules on fields that i don't want triggered

Tags: infopath-rules

i use the rule below to set default values for fields on the left that i want to be able to change if necessary to other values before saving the form.

the problem is that when i save and then reload the form, it triggers the rule to reset the values back to their defaults!

how can i get around this??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a helper field to help decide whether to apply the rules or not. For example, if you want the rules to fire only for a new form, check if the ID field is empty and only run the rules if it is.

Or, use a field called, for e.g., "CustomSettings". Depending on what you want to do with the form, set "CustomSettings" to a specific value. Run or don't run the rules according to that field's value.

Comment: i set a ReadOnly field upon initial form submit and then if the ReadOnly is False i run the rules. the problem now, is that i want the form to be editable - and if the user wants to refresh the fields, then i want the rules to run again. it seems so much clutter to have them have to check a box saying "edit these values" basically.

Comment: Well, if you want to toggle between read only and write, there will need to be a trigger for that. InfoPath can be a bit cumbersome at times, I agree.

Comment: Do you know if there are any plans for an "on click" event?